# Unable to Decode Stream: fileNotFoundException when trying to show an image from URL

Tags: java, android, eclipse

this is my code

```
{
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")

    public static Bitmap getbmp(String src)
    {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try ( InputStream is = new URL( src ).openStream() )
        {
              bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( is );
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

     return bm;
     }
}
```

Then I call it it throws

> Unable to Decode Stream: fileNotFoundException

Comment: Please post the entire Java stack trace, and indicate what the value of `src` is.

Comment: I don't have the Android libraries ready, but I made a small example just printing the bitmap data as a String. This seems to work fine with a random image of the internet. I suspect the problem is in you src.

Comment: its a URL and that's the url : https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/webservices/aws_logo._V400518270_.png

@CommonsWare

Comment: I suspect the same as the previous commentators. But taking another step back - if you need the bitmap for an ImageView - I suggest that you use Picasso library.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(src).getContent());
```